# Z-index causes mouse interaction with video to fail

Tags: html, css

i'm working on my portfolio (http://lab.robinandersen.no/) and my problem is that I cant seem to press play on the video *(scroll down to the orange square)*

I think the reason is because i use a div in front to keep the footer and the header floating on top of it all. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I can press the play button fine, what browser are you using ?

a fix could be to add z-index to the video e.g

```
#work video {
height: auto;
width: 100%;
margin: -3;
z-index: 99;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a wrapper tag.

If you change that to `div id="wrapper"` and add styles for that like so:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
```

then style the header like so:

```
width: 400px;
text-align: center;
position: fixed;
margin: 0 auto;
```

and also move the `#work` div within the wrapper. It should work for you.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it with removing the top div :) and adding position: fixed to header and fotter instead! Dont know why I used that div! 

Thanks anyway :)